# Precondition not satisfied when calling function in another module

Tags: functional-programming, formal-verification, fstar

I'm trying to call a function in another module that is responsible for ensuring the pre/post conditions on the heap are preserved. Specifically it ensures that the string passed in is "readable" before calling read:

```
val readableFiles : ref fileList
let readableFiles = ST.alloc []

let checkedRead f =
  if canRead !readableFiles f
  then read f
  else failwith "unreadable"
```

This allows it satisfy the read precondition which is defined as follows:

```
let canRead (readList : fileList) (f : filename) =
  Some? (tryFind (function x -> x = f) readList)
type canRead_t f h = canRead (sel h readableFiles) f == true

val read : f:filename -> All string
  (requires (canRead_t f)) (ensures (fun h x h' -> True))
let read f = FStar.IO.print_string ("Dummy read of file " ^ f ^ "\n"); f
```

When I create a main function and call `checkedRead "file"` it works fine, however when I attempt to use this module inside of another module it complains with the following error:

```
TestAccess.fst(34,11-34,19): (Error 19) assertion failed (see also <fstar_path>/fstar/ulib/FStar.All.fst(36,40-36,45))
Verified module: TestAccess (3912 milliseconds)
```

This is the same error that you would see if you attempted to call `read` directly without using `checkedRead` (in the main file), implying that the compiler does not believe the precondition is met.

If I duplicate `checkedRead` (and only that function) in the other file it works properly. So it seems like the compiler can't infer that this satisfies the condition across the module boundaries.

How can I use the `checkedRead`function from the other file without having to redefine it locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the advice of Nik Swamy, I added a type annotation to `checkedRead` which fixed the issue:

```
val checkedRead : filename -> All string
  (requires (fun h -> True)) (ensures (fun h x h' -> True))
let checkedRead f =
  if canRead !readableFiles f
  then read f
  else failwith "unreadable"
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a complete example, please?

A tip: it's good practice to annotate the type of your top-level functions. That will help you confirm that the type F* infers is the one you expect, which can be helpful when diagnosing these kinds of verification failures.

Comment: Type annotating `checkedRead` solved the issue for me! I've posted an answer with the fix.